# This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered (for no reason)

Tags: node.js, sass

I'm rendering a simple sass file and getting the following warnings:

```
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.
   ╷
14 │     position:fixed
   │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵

WARNING on line 17, column 9 of test.sass: 
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.
   ╷
17 │         display:inline-block
   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

Here's the file:

```
html, body 
    width:100%
    min-height:100vh
    margin:0
    padding:0
.header
    background-color:#ffffffb2
    border-bottom:#0000004c
    box-shadow:0 0 20px #0000004c
    top:0px
    left:0px
    right:0px
    height:70px
    position:fixed
    a
        font-size:1rem
        display:inline-block
        padding:2rem 3rem
        color:#0000004c
```

I really need those position and display styles to be rendered in the output css and I can't see any reason why sass would be complaining about them. Does anyone see a problem in my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a white space after the `:`s, checkout the [DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/d2fc21b07ec0cdd8593f5505d4966015)