# SASS code error does not identify line error

Tags: sass

I am getting an error from the code below and I have been unable to identify the error. This is a quasar app

Without providing a code line, the error shows "Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.

null"

This link doesn't appear to help as there shouldn't be a space after hover. [This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered (for no reason)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59513025/this-selector-doesnt-have-any-properties-and-wont-be-rendered-for-no-reason)

```
.GL
&__select-GL__menu-link
 .default-type
   color: black
   visibility: hidden
&:hover
  background: black
  color: black
  .default-type
  color: black
    visibility: visible
&__toolbar-link
a
  color: black
  text-decoration: none
  &:hover
    opacity: 0.7
 &__menu-link:hover
background: b-primary
color: black
&__menu-link-signed-in,
&__menu-link-status
&:hover
  & > div
    background: white !important
    color: black
&__menu-link-status
  &:hover
  color: black
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Sass code seems to be indented incorrectly and/or missing commas between selector lists. Dumping your code as-is into the [Sass playground](https://sass-lang.com/playground/#eJx9kLFuwzAMRHd9Bbt4iox0KuCha5b8gyFLbExEJg2Zduu/b+wEiOwA2STx7t5Rx8/ydDZFXQ8Y0as9neu6Qx5tJL4aKAP+uDGq1blHAwBeoqQKmuj8dblPNFBDkXSuoKUQkE1RtTJhuk2bm+iSZOTwdOwC9oB9/gawniMudVUkNi7da7pXo+Kf2oBeklMSroCFl/xnOQDpnV9zj+WXgSJb/CHa9Ld9os6l2WxIucsOdGEMlviwe1en45B9TAHfEGhaW+SQ35YU4YO6XpI61lXwhnfPzbfKxf/kNJ0E), we get the errors:

```
@warn:1
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.

@warn:9
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.

@warn:12
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.

@error:18
Inconsistent indentation, expected 2 spaces.
   ╷
18 │  &__menu-link:hover
   │ ^
   ╵
  - 18:1  root stylesheet
```

Possible corrected Sass code:

```
.GL
  &__select-GL__menu-link
   .default-type
     color: black
     visibility: hidden
  &:hover
    background: black
    color: black
    .default-type
      color: black
      visibility: visible
  &__toolbar-link,
  a
    color: black
    text-decoration: none
    &:hover
      opacity: 0.7
  &__menu-link:hover
    background: b-primary
    color: black
  &__menu-link-signed-in,
  &__menu-link-status,
  &:hover
    & > div
      background: white !important
      color: black
  &__menu-link-status
    &:hover
      color: black
```

See this compile with no warnings or errors in [this Sass playground](https://sass-lang.com/playground/#eJx1kDFuwzAMRfeegl0yWUY6BfDQNUvuYMgSExORSUOmnfj2dewgUBt1Iz75+fi5/yqPpw+AXV0PGNCpOZ7qukMeTSC+Lh0oPZ7tGNTo3ONDAHASJFbQBOuumzLRQA0F0rmClrxHfiytWpkwrhPNMnqJMrJPfW+LMrAM7RdurQNuIVQkNDauxxeLZPMYxbsaj06iVRKugIU3XHozgPTWrZB9edgAr9f8l830kTob5xw49ZuBLozeEBdvHbU6DsWfD+7gGzxNz8tS5q0lRfikrpeoljX/twwikzg1/QC0FqU8).

Comment: Thank you for the help, your thorough answer, and the great link to the playground